# Can't get data from the task object of salesforce to display in visualforce page

Tags: pdf, apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to render as a pdf the comments that are associated with a task. I have created a custom button but when I try to get the data to display there is nothing but the field name and I need the text that is stored.

Here is my code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Task" renderAs="PDF">
    <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock">
         <apex:pageblocktable value="{!task}" var="AC" id="acTable">
            <apex:column value="{!AC.description}"/>

        </apex:Pageblocktable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I did not create a controller class and have no idea how to do this. Basically I store a sent email in the comments and want to print it so if that field can show as a pdf I would be set.

Answer (score 0):

modify permissions for field & object on profile & object level.

Comment: I have that just don't know if my code is right and if I need a controller